# How can I clear the console with golang in windows?

Tags: windows, go

I've tried a lot of ways, like

```
package main 
import (
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    c := exec.Command("cls")
    c.Stdout = os.Stdout
    c.Run()
}
```

and

```
C.system(C.CString("cls"))
```

And the escape sequence doesn't work either

Comment: Since this will entirely depend on your OS and console, you should add what OS you're using. If windows it looks like you'll need to do a system() call to "cls" as "cls" is not an executable (which is what exec expects)

Comment: Got it, I'm a newbie of Stack Overflow. I had added the windows tag.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All you need is :

```
package main

import (
"os"
"os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("cmd", "/c", "cls")
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Run()
}
```

Comment: It seems weird, but your code just works in windows. Why should we call the "cmd" with the "cls" argument instead of calling the "cls" directly. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: The reason is that "cls" is a builtin command into the DOS "shell" and not a standalone executable. So when you type "cls" it just clears the screen of your running shell but never runs an external command. When you run a command in go you run commands directly and not through a shell. HTH

Comment: how would you do it for nix systems?

Answer (score 11):

There's really no easy way to do this in a cross-platform way using the standard libraries.

[`termbox-go`](https://github.com/nsf/termbox-go) seems to be one library providing cross-platform terminal control. There are probably others, but it's the only one I've used and it seems to work well.

Clearing the console using `termbox-go` would be a matter of doing a [`Clear`](http://godoc.org/github.com/nsf/termbox-go#Clear) and then a [`Flush`](http://godoc.org/github.com/nsf/termbox-go#Flush).

See http://godoc.org/github.com/nsf/termbox-go for more details.

Answer (score 4):

For linux and mac in case someone needs it:

```
fmt.Println("\033[2J")
```

Comment: It clear but leave the spaces on the top, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the  playground ["Conway's Game of Life"](https://play.golang.org/p/jibIOKi7wqW), you can see how they  clear the terminal by means of a specific instruction:

`//line 110
fmt.Print("\x0c", l)`

Comment: It's not clearing the terminal, it is appending. Verified on mac.