# system("clear"); equivalent in Go

Tags: go

Could anyone show me the equivalent in go to the system("clear"); in C ? I want to clean the console after a certain period of time. Thanks in advance

EDIT: This worked for me in Linux

```
import "os/exec"

// Method body
clear := exec.Command("clear")
clear.Stdout = os.Stdout
clear.Run()
```

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19209425/how-can-i-clear-the-console-with-golang-in-windows

Comment: It really helped, thank you!!!! works almost the same way for Linux

Comment: since the edit is a solution and not a question, can you submit it as such.

Answer (score 3):

The go function below is equivalent to the C system() function.  In go you could use this like:

```golang
import "system"

...
    exitstatus := system.System("clear")
```

Here is the Go code:

```golang
package system

import (
        "os"
        "os/exec"
        "syscall"
    )

func System(cmd string) int {
    c := exec.Command("sh", "-c", cmd)
    c.Stdin = os.Stdin
    c.Stdout = os.Stdout
    c.Stderr = os.Stderr
    err := c.Run()

    if err == nil {
        return 0
    }

    // Figure out the exit code
    if ws, ok := c.ProcessState.Sys().(syscall.WaitStatus); ok {
        if ws.Exited() {
            return ws.ExitStatus()
        }

        if ws.Signaled() {
            return -int(ws.Signal())
        }
    }

    return -1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `stdlib.h` system function in `go` by using few lines of `C`:

```
package main

// #include <stdlib.h>
//
// void clear() {
//  system("clear");
// }
import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello")
    fmt.Println("World")
    fmt.Println("Golang")

    time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)

    C.clear()

    fmt.Println("Screen is cleared")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`system()` in C calls an external program — `clear` in your case.

So the equivalent in Go would be using the [`os/exec`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/) standard package to spawn the same program and wait for it to complete its execution.