# golang - open file in an empty bash window

Tags: bash, go, buffer

lets say I have this code:

```
package main 

import (
     "io/ioutil" 
     "fmt"
)
func check(err error) {
     if err != nil {
         panic(err)
     }
} 
func main() {
     file, err := ioutil.ReadFile("test.txt")
     check(err)
     fmt.Print(string(file))
}
```

when running it with `go run` I want it to be written in a cleared bash window. Is it possible to do so without using any additional open-source repositories?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by written in a cleared buffer?

Comment: I've editted the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I clear the terminal screen in Go?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891644/how-can-i-clear-the-terminal-screen-in-go); and [How can I clear the console with golang in windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19209425/how-can-i-clear-the-console-with-golang-in-windows)

Comment: You do it the same is you would in any language. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084508/clear-terminal-in-python

Answer (score 1):

If clearing the terminal is truly part of your program's responsibility then check out the answers in this question [How can I clear the terminal screen in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891644/how-can-i-clear-the-terminal-screen-in-go)

However if you're just wanting to clear the screen as part of your development process then I would keep it simple and do something like this

```
clear && go run *.go
```